# When is a file created when using output redirection?

Tags: filesystems, ksh, aix, wc

I have a script that runs in AIX ksh that looks like this:

```
wc dir1/* dir2/* | {awk command to rearrange output} | {grep command to filter more} > dir2/output.txt
```

It is a precondition to this line that dir2/output.txt does not exist.

The issue is that dir2/output.txt has contained itself in the output (it's happened a handful of times out of hundreds of times with no problem). dir1 and dir2 are NFS-mounted.

Is it related to the implementation of `wc` -- what if the the first parameter takes a long time? I think not, as I've tried the following:

```
wc `sleep 5` *.txt > out.txt
```

Even in this case out.txt does not list itself.

As a last note, wildcards are used in this example where they are used in the actual script. So if the expansion happens first, why does this problem occur?

At what point is dir2/output.txt actually created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirections are done by the shell, as are globs.  Your problem is that, in the case of a pipeline, each pipeline stage is a separate subprocess; whether the shell subprocess that does the final redirection runs before the one that builds the glob of input files for `wc` will depend on details of the scheduler and system load, among other things, and should be considered indeterminate.

In short, you should assume that this will happen and either exclude `dir2/output.txt` (take a look at `ksh` extended glob patterns; in particular, something along the lines of `dir2/!(output.txt)` may be useful) or create the output somewhere else and `mv` it to its final location afterward.

Comment: I had always just thought that if a subprocess was waiting for input, it wouldn't be able to create any output.

I think this clears up a lot of incorrect assumptions I had, all in  one shot.